# Windows file saving conflicts between machines on a USB flash drive - very weird?

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I have encountered an issue with saving/modifying files on a single USB flash drive. We got a program called "[Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze/enterprise/)" and the windows user has no admin rights on the PC. When the student used his USB flash drive to create/modify files on it, he sees the changes but they don't carry over when the USB flash drive is used on a different PC. But when the flash drive is used on a PC without Deep Freeze, and with admin rights, it works as expected.

I tried the following test: I created a file named 111.txt with "h" in it, and then moved to a different computer with the file did not show. I then created a new 111.txt file with "q" in it in the computer with the admin rights. I check on several other computers (with and w/o admin rights) and they all show the 111.txt file with the "q" in it. But when I go back to the first computer, it shows the 111.txt file and when I open it it shows the "h".

I tried to regenerate this issue with a different USB flash drive - and it does not happen. Any other flash drive functions just fine.

Anyone have any idea what is going on with the machine? It is a Windows 7 Pro SP1 x32 machine.

Comment: Are the flash drives deep-frozen according to the configuration? Deep-frozen drives don't have changes written to them; instead, the changes are written to a temporary location on the harddrive, which is simply wiped on every boot. Any time a program views a folder or file, deepfreeze then overlays these temporary changes over what is actually on the disk to give the appearance of writing to the drive.

Comment: Its happens only with one flash drive.I tried a different drive and it was just fine. So the USB is not frozen. Any other idea?

Comment: Is the filesystem on the USB flash drive NTFS or FAT32? Do you see the same behavior if you thaw the computers?

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul - So if its a single drive then it must be the drive itself.  Your question indicates this happens to more then one user with any USB.  Clarlify the question.

Comment: @Ramhound, I rewrote the question. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul - Sounds like the problem is with the drive itself.  Sounds like the drive is protected.  I would just use a different drive at this point.  One could also try formatting the drive to see if that helps.  Specifice information on the drive might be helpful.